# Exponential Integral difference between Maple and Matlab

Tags: definite-integrals, matlab, maple

I try to calculate this exponential integral:

$$\int_0^1 \exp(\exp(-s))ds.$$

I obtained different results in Maple:

[image: Maple]

and Matlab:

[image: Matlab]

Which is correct?

Answer (score 3):

The two apparently different answers are in fact the same.

This is the consequence of the different notations used, with the relationship :
$$ei(x)=-Ei(1,-x)$$
The typography in softwares are not exactly standard, respectively :
$ei(x)\equiv Ei(x)$ and $Ei(1,x)\equiv E_1(x)$
with reference to:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral
 and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html , equation (3).

Comment: However, in matlab , the result is a real number 1.9132 .While in maple, it's a complex number. I prefer to the result in Matlab. Could you explain more ? thanks

Comment: $-Ei(1)=E_1(-1)=-1.8951178...\:\:$ and $-Ei(e^{-1})=E_1(-e^{-1})=0.01810250...$ Hense, with the notations of Maple : $$-Ei(1,-1)+Ei(1,-e^{-1})=1.8951178+0.01810250=1.9132203...$$ Maple gives the same real result than Matlab. Do not confuse $E_1(x)$ which is noted $Ei(1,x)$ in Maple and $Ei(x)$ wich is noted $ei(x)$ in Mathlab.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will learn more from your comments

Answer (score 0):

```
H := int(exp(exp(-s)),s=0..1);

                   H := -Ei(1, -1) + Ei(1, -exp(-1))

evalf(H);

                          1.913220322 + 0. I

simplify(%);

                              1.913220322

evalc(H);

                          Ei(1) - Ei(exp(-1))

evalf(%);

                              1.913220322
```

Comment: Hi, acer, See you again. Thanks for you help. I'm seriously to inform you that you really know so much. Appreciating